# chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have developed an extension with links inside, once user hover over these links a tooltip appear describing the link, the problem when the link close to the border of the extension popup the tooltip appears but part of it not all the contents inside these tooltip, I think because it's below the frame of the popup.

Is it possible to make the tooltip appears above the frame of the popup?

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

If you're implementing tooltips with `title=` attributes, you can't control where they are positioned. However you can create your own tooltips in JS and position them as within the bounds of the popup, using something like [Tipped](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/tipped/). A quick search will bring up hundreds of other libraries.

Comment: i'm using css3 to represent the tooltip and it works fine but the problem with the popup borders, is there a way to overcome this???

Comment: hi again, here is my extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhajbkoenjgmiimdobilplibaboeiocb

Comment: FYI, you can use `::before` and `::after` to make pseudo elements in CSS3.